# Sending and getting parameters through Delete method in express.js using axios as client

Tags: javascript, express, heroku

Please I have written an API in express js for a DELETE request which checks for a **password** parameter before doing other things. This whole thing works locally on postman, but not with the hosted server on heroku.

Here is a snippet from the API

```
  ...
 if (!req.body.password) {
   return res.status(400).json({ message: "input password"})
  }
  ...
```

And on my Client side, I have

```
axios.delete('url/id', ({password: 'password'}))
 .then()
 .catch()
```

The Issue is this, req.body.password is not being noticed, it is seen as undefined on the hosted server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not common to pass something into delete body so it's different than post, put and patch requests [as you can see here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/897)

You should do it like this:

```
axios.delete('/some/uri', { data: 'my delete body' })
```